# 'or' query with different data types in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sails.js, waterline

Given routes

```
GET /user/42
GET /user/dude
```

where 42 is user id and dude is username.

So, I want to have method in my controller that return user for both cases. Here it is:

```
// api/controllers/UserController.js
findOne: function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
        or: [
            {id: req.params.id},
            {username: req.params.id}
        ]
    }).exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        res.json(user);
    });
},
```

When I try to `GET /user/42` everything is fine.

When I try to `GET /user/dude` I get error:

> Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
>
> error: invalid input syntax for integer: "dude"

It seems like sails refuses to process `{id: 'dude'}` because of type mismatch.

I am using sails 0.10.5 with sails-postgresql 0.10.9. So what am I doing wrong?

**UPD:** I do know how to solve problem. Of course I can put if statement to my controller and check what type of parameter it got. Actually, I just created two routes with regexp parameters that point to single method.

**My actual problem** is why I can not do this with `or`. Does sails provide such way?

Answer (score 1):

> By default, sails get method only supports id numbers. You will need
>   to define custom routes and implement the relevant api method to
>   support a get request using a string instead of a number.

---

**Technical Details:** 
To solve your exact problem, you need to define the following route in your routes.js

```
module.exports.routes = {
...
  '/user/get/:param': 'UserController.findByIDorName', 
...
}
```

This will pass anything after the /user/get/ as the parameter named 'param' to the findByIDorName controller method.

Next you need to check the type of the param and decide if you want to fetch the user info based on the id or the name, so add this function in your userController.js

```
findByIDorName : function (req, res) {
         if (isNaN(req.param)){
              //find the user by his username after any validation you need
         }
         else {
             //find the user by his id and return
         }
}
```

Comment: I do. I am not using blueprints at all.

Comment: I added some details how you need to handle this in the routes and controller.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I have upvoted your answer but it does not solve my actual problem. I update question for more details

Comment: It seems the sails internal implementation is a bit different for both findOne and populate, but you are going against the laws in populate too :)  you should detect the type (validate) and then pass it to the db query so that you do not query an id against a string in any scenario (mayb the next version of sails break the populate too?)